# Twilio PHP Web Hooks?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I have a webhook in Twilio using Studio and most of it is working fine right up to getting the response back from the web server.

Looking in the Twilio log I can see the response coming back like so:

```
  "widgets": {
    "ReplyWithJobDetail": {},
    "AskServer": {
      "status_code": 200,
      "content_type": "text/xml",
      "body": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Response><Message>Thank you for accepting this position.<From>From=MCC</From><Body>Body=Here is the body content</Body></Message></Response>"
    },
```

But I am getting an error in Twilio stating:

```
Body: 
Failure sending message: Message body is required.
```

Which is odd because the body is obviously there.

My webhook is:

```
function trigger_receive_sms($from) {
  header ('Content-Type:text/xml');
  echo ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
  echo ('<Response>');
  echo ('<Message>Thank you for accepting this position.');
  echo ('<From>From=MCC</From>');
  echo ('<Body>Body=Here is the body content</Body>');
  echo ('</Message>');
  echo ('</Response>');
  die();
}
```

This is in WordPress and also have the Twilio.Core plugin installed.

I have been trying to get this working for 4 days...Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I didn't get your question right I apologize. I'm not clear how your setup is, what your Studio flow contains, what's with WordPress, etc...

Here is the TwiML to respond to an incoming message:

```xml
<Response>
    <Message>Hello from Twilio!</Message>
</Response>
```

There is no need for `From` because it will be sent from your Twilio's number, and the `body` of the message is right between the `<Messsage>` tags, so there is also no need for `<Body>` tags.

As such, try with:

```php
function trigger_receive_sms($from) {
  header ('Content-Type:text/xml');
  echo ('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
  echo ('<Response>');
  echo ('<Message>Thank you for accepting this position.');
  echo ('</Message>');
  echo ('</Response>');
  die();
}
```

Let us know how it goes. If I got it wrong, please give more details, I'll try to understand better.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I tried that previously but I still get "Message Body is Required". The widget that is falling over is here: https://paste.pics/5RVYH

Comment: I am trying to get the response from this widget: https://paste.pics/5RVYR 

When I look at the response in the Studio logs I can see that it returning this:

  "widgets": {
    "ReplyWithJobDetail": {},
    "AskServer": {
      "status_code": 200,
      "content_type": "text/xml",
      "body": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Response><Message>Thank you for accepting this position.</Message></Response>"
    },

Comment: I worked out the problem, the return data needs to be JSON not XML, so now to work out how to convert it to JSON :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just needed to convert the output to JSON...

Did that with the following:

```
function trigger_receive_sms($from) {
  header ('Content-Type:application/json');
  $message = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  $message .= '<Response>';
  $message .= '<Message>Thank you for accepting this position.';
  $message .= '</Message>';
  $message .= '</Response>';
  $simplexml = simplexml_load_string($message);
  $json = json_encode($simplexml);
  return $json;
  die();
}
```

Comment: Hi Alex, turns out i'm not quite there yet... some weird behavior when the JSON lands at Twilio...  when I hit my webhook in a browser it looks like this: "{\"message\":\"Thank you for accepting this position.\",\"from\":\"MCC\"}"

However when it hit Twilio it looks like this:       "body": "\"{\\\"message\\\":\\\"Thank you for accepting this position.\\\",\\\"from\\\":\\\"MCC\\\"}\"" and subsequently fails.

I have tried replacing \\ with "" before the return but that didn't change anything. Have you seen this behavior before?

Comment: It's a guess, but I don't think you should pass XML to json_encode(), try to build and array then pass it to json_encode().

Comment: it's interesting, if I return hand coded JSON like this:   header ('Content-Type:application/json');
  return '{"Message":"Thank you for accepting this position.","From":"From MCC","Body":"Hello"}';

It still shows wrong in Twilio so json_encode doesn't seem to be the problem. I have been back and forth with the Twilio team and they are just as confused. I have tried this on 3 different WordPress sites now all with the same result... quite frustrating, perhaps WordPress doing something funky somewhere?

Comment: I can try to help you but I don't have a good understanding how the entire process/application is set up. Could you update your question giving more details, as much as you can, especially about the Studio flow (maybe a screen capture)?

Comment: Thanks Alex, I might actually mark this thread as complete and create a new thread as the actual problem has changed from the original problem.

Comment: Sounds good, maybe this needs to be done with a Twilio function if Studio's widgets don't like the data that's coming back from WordPress.